# VUEJS - Bind the return from my method to my child template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to bind the return from my method to my child template.

**methods object**

```
  methods: {
    filterOptions(checkedValues: any) {
      let filtered = this.cards.filter(card => {
        return card.profile
                .map(profile => profile.salary)
                .find(profileSalary => {
                  return checkedValues.find((salaryOption: number) => {
                    return profileSalary >= salaryOption;
                  });
                });
      });
    }
  }
```

template

```
<template>
  <section id="app">
    <Gallery v-bind:filtered="filtered"/>
  </section>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of objects as a parameter to the child component.

[See the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

### Child

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-for="item in arr"
            :key="item.id">{{ item.name }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Child',
        params: {
            arr: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => []
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

### Parent

```
<template>
    <div>
        <child :arr="parentArray"/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Child from './Child.vue'
    export default {
        name: 'Parent',
        components: {
            Child
        },
        computed: {
            parentArray () {
                return [...whatever]
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```